# windows forms, c# Passing values depending on the label chosen

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, variables

I have a small game, this game have 5 diferent window forms, each window have diferent designs.

First: Welcome page, with play and rules
Second: Level choice
third: Actuall game
fourth: Store to buy gadgets

I use this to open the new window and close the previous one

```
 FormMain formMain = new FormMain();
            formMain.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

How can I pass variables to the new page, in both cases, the form sending and the form receiving. I tried this

```
formMain.Show(x, y);
```

But the show class implies other stuff.

My point is:

1 - depending on the label shosen with the level (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), I pass diferent values to the enemies, so I don´t have to create one form to each level.

2 - Choosing gadgets in the store passes to the game form to increase the player win.

Comment: have you tried with public properties?

Comment: There are many good examples here showing how to pass values between forms.

Comment: Hello, is it possible to take a look at the answer I provided?

Comment: Yes offcourse, I am currently working in one big project, so I am dedicating time to both projects. As soon as I test it, I will let you know. Thank you very much for your time and dedication!

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of options but ill list a few:

1 passing data via the constructor of the Form/Class

```
public ClassName(int var1, int var2)
{
    //do something with var1 and var2
}
```

this might not be the best option if you want to do some animation with the passed data.

2 setting public variables after the class were created

```
public class ClassName()
{
    public int var1, var2;
}
```

elsewhere in code

```
ClassName clObject = new ClassName();
clObject.var1 = 1;
clObject.var2 = 2;
clObject.Show();
```

3 calling a method to pass the data

```
public class ClassName()
{
    private int var1, var2;
    public void DoTheThing(int var1, int var2)
    {
         //do something with the data
    }
}
```

elsewhere in code

```
ClassName clObject = new ClassName();
clObject.Show();
clObject.DoTheThing(1,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of the second form and access the public methods easily. I leave an example below.

```
// Click Event On First(Main) Form
private void ParameterSelect_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                    string value = "Test";
                    var secondFormInstance = new SecondForm();             
                    var result = secondFormInstance.SwitchExampleMethod(value);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Error while click event. Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
// Second Form Method
public string SwitchExampleMethod(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "Test":
                    case "Test1":
                    case "Test2":
                    case "Test3":
                        return "This value string for just a Test.";
                    case "Insane":
                    case "Wow":
                        return "This is amazing string text.";
                    default:
                        return "This is default string text.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Error on switch. Error : {ex.Message}");
                return $"Error on switch. Error : {ex.Message}";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it is suggested that you use the method of static variable passing by value. This method's pass-by-value is bidirectional.

The sample code is as follows:

**Define a static member value in an app class:**

```
 public class app
    {
        public static string value;
    }
```

**In the form Form1 call like this:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    app.value = "f2"; //Assign values to static members
    new Form2().Show(); //Show Form2
}
```

**In the form Form2:**

```
 public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = App.value; //Get back the value of app.value
        app.value = "Form2"; //Assign a value to app.value so that other forms can call
    }
```